# Covert a Pyspark Dataframe into a List with actual values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a Pyspark dataframe column to a list of values ***NOT*** objects.

Now my ultimate goal is use it as a filter for filtering another dataframe.

I have tries the following:

```
X = df.select("columnname").collect()
```

But when I use it to filter I am unable to.

```
Y = dtaframe.filter(~dtaframe.columnname.isin(X)))
```

Also, tried to convert into numpy Array and aggregate collect_list()

```
df.groupby('columnname').agg(collect_list(df["columnname"])
```

Please advise.

Comment: try `dataframe.filter(~F.col("columnname").isin([x[0] for x in df.select("columname").collect()]))`

Comment: Takes time but works! Thanks.

Comment: the `collect` is executing everytime the list hits it. try assigning the collect to a variable and then traverse it like `a=df.select("columnname").collect()` then `dataframe.filter(~F.col("columnname").isin([x[0] for x in a]))` so it only collects once

Comment: OOM error, running it twice for dataframes, any advise?? ~3M records

Comment: generally, it is almost never advisable to `collect` from one dataframe and use it to `filter` on another. ur logic could be expressed using `join` or `exceptAll` depending on what ur dataframes look like. try a `left_anti` join like this `dataframe.join(df.select("columnname"),["columnname"],how='left_anti')`

Comment: using `collect` basically collects all ur data **`from ur executors to your driver node`** which has `limited memory` which is why u got the out of memory error(OOM).

Comment: `left_anti join` over `collect()_then_filter` any day. for big data u simply cannot `collect()`.  @anky

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi thanks yeah i was thinking the same

Answer (score 1):

Collect function returns an array of row object by collecting the data from executors. If you need an array of values in native datatypes, it has to be handled explicitly to fetch the column from the row object.

This code creates a DF with column number of LongType.

```
df = spark.range(0,10,2).toDF("number")
```

Convert this into a python list.

```
num_list = [row.number for row in df.collect()]
```

Now this list can used in any dataframe to filter the values using isin function.

```
df1 = spark.range(10).toDF("number")
df1.filter(~col("number").isin(num_list)).show()
```